# JSchemaGenerator omits "$scema" in output

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I am using Newtonsoft's JSchemaGenerator to generate schema from .Net objects ([see the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm)).

Is there a way to make output of the generated schema to include   `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"`?

It is defined in [Json Schema specifications](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.7) as

> The "$schema" keyword is both used as a JSON Schema version identifier and the location of a resource which is itself a JSON Schema, which describes any schema written for this particular version.

Comment: Generated from what? The JSON Schema specification describes validation of data based on a schema. You'll have to consult the specific tool you are using to generate schemas. There is no standardized approach.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers, I mentioned specific tool I am using. I edited the question to make it more clear.